# Windows Phone ListBox Circle Image View

Tags: xaml, c#-4.0, windows-phone-8

My Requirement is i need to display my ListBox with Some Images in Circle View like Below image

[image]

i search more but i didn't find any thing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In XAML you want to make the circle using an Ellipse control. Then give it an ImageBrush fill.

```
<Ellipse>
    <Ellipse.Fill>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="YourImage.png"/>
    </Ellipse.Fill>
</Ellipse>
```